# How to Unhook windows hooks

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook

I have a program (not a DLL) that creates a thread, and in this thread I create a hook using `SetWindowsHookExW()` to get keyboard events. I also have a global variable that I can use to turn off this thread.

The thing is that I don't know how to release the hooks and continue the function/thread, because it also does some cleanup. When I use `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` and place breakpoints in the following lines, the breakpoints are never reached.

The example on MSDN is *"broken"*, because it needs an `app.h`; Also, every tutorial on the Internet, either input systems, keylogger, etc, they talk about DLLs, that I'm not using, and some of them implement a wrapper Unhook function but they never use it.

What I've been trying:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

bool bContinue;
wchar_t vkTecla;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardCallBack(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        vkTecla = ((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode;

        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }
        // ...
    }

    if (bContinue)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        return 0;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void MainThread(HANDLE hfile)
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardCallBack, 0, 0);

    MSG msg;
    // I tested these 3 cases
    /*************/
    while(GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0));
    // Or
    GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
    /*************/
    while(GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    /*************/
    while (bContinue)
    {
        // PeekMessage(...);
        GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    // In this example I would remove the other Unhook function
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    /*************/

    CloseHandle(hfile);
}
```

If I do the first example, the:

```cpp
while(GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0));
```

and check `bContinue` inside of the callback function;

or use the third one:

```cpp
while (bContinue)
{
    GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
```

And place a breakpoint in `CloseHandle(hArquivo);`, when I make the `bContinue = false`, this line never gets executed.

So the question is:

- Where do I place `UnhookWindowsHookEx()`? Is it inside the Callback function, or somewhere else?
- When I release the hook, will the thread continue? Because at the moment, I don't get the program to stop at breakpoints past the *unhooking* that have some cleanup.

Comment: It doesn't look like you created a user interface at all.  So how do let your user tell you that they want the program to stop running?  That missing code, that's where UnhookWindowsHookEx() or PostQuitMessage() belongs.  Shell_NotifyIcon(), for example, is a simple way to let your user interact with your program.

Comment: A low-level keyboard hook is highly intrusive. It gets executed for **every** keyboard input, needs to be executed strictly in sequence with other hooks of the same type, and thus adds to the system's overall response time for every keyboard input. It should be used strictly in cases where you intend to reject input. If all you need is to observe keyboard input, use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMessage()` is a blocking function.  It will not exit until the message queue of the calling thread has a message available for the caller to process.

But, you are running this code in a worker thread that has no UI of its own.  And, although hooks do use messaging internally, they are private to the hook implementation and the caller of `(Peek|Get)Message()` will never see them.  So, unless the other threads in your app are posting messages to this worker thread via `PostThreadMessage()`, there are simply no messages for `GetMessage()` to return to your code.  That is why your loop doesn't break.

So, you need to either:

- use `PeekMessage()` instead of `GetMessage()` so you can monitor your `bContinue` variable in between polls of the message queue:

```
#include <Windows.h>

bool bContinue = TRUE;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardCallBack(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        wchar_t vkTecla = ((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode;

        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }

        // ...
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void MainThread(HANDLE hfile)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardCallBack, 0, 0);
    MSG msg;

    while (bContinue)
    {
        if (PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
            Sleep(10);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);

    CloseHandle(hfile);
}

...

// to stop the thread:
bContinue = FALSE;
```

- change `bContinue` to be a `HANDLE` returned by `CreateEvent()`, and then use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` in a loop to monitor that event and the message queue at the same time, calling `(Get|Peek)Message()` only when it reports the message queue has messages to process.  Then you can use `SetEvent()` when you want to trigger the loop to end.

```
#include <Windows.h>

HANDLE hStop = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardCallBack(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        wchar_t vkTecla = ((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode;

        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }

        // ...
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void MainThread(HANDLE hfile)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardCallBack, 0, 0);
    MSG msg;

    while (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &hStop, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) == (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1))
    {
        while (PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);

    CloseHandle(hfile);
}

...

// to stop the thread:
SetEvent(hStop);
```

Comment: Yeah, changing GetMessage() to PeekMessage() did work, I thought that GetMessage() would return at some point, like how it works when creating a window since booth use the same function; looks like "hooks" works diferent.

Comment: Hooks don't work different. It's just that the system will generate messages if there is a window (such as `WM_MOUSEMOVE`), so `GetMessage` returns more frequently in that environment. The ground rules haven't changed, though.